# あってから usage and あったから usage

Tags: て-form

こんにちは, Im quite new to this platform and also japanese, but recently a question struck me. How do I say , "Because I feel pain, I feel alive" or "Because I feel pain, I know that Im alive" Which is better,  痛みがあったから、「生きている」を感じる or 痛みがあってから、「生きている」を感じる ? If there is any better ones, could some kind soul suggest it and correct me? どうもありがとう!

Answer (score 2):

から in 「て-form + から」 (あってから) is a case particle meaning "after doing~~".
から in 「terminal form + から」 (あったから/あるから) is a conjunctive particle meaning "because~~".

So 痛みがあってから means "after I feel/felt pain".
痛みがあったから means "because I felt pain". (あった is the past form of ある)

> "Because I feel pain, I feel alive"

I would say 「痛みがあるから、『生きている』と感じる。」 using ある and quotative と.